# How to insert and return an instance of Employee (DAO pattern)

Tags: java, sql, resultset

In method `save()` I receive as input an instance of Employee, and I want to add it to the table `employee` and return this added instance. I read about this problem but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

```
public Employee save(Employee employee) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = ConnectionSource.instance().createConnection();
        String sql = "insert into employee VALUES(" +employee.getId() + ", " + "'employee.getFullName().getFirstName()'" + ", " +"'employee.getFullName().getLastName()'"+ ", " +"'employee.getFullName().getMiddleName()'"+ ", " +  "'employee.getPosition()'" + ", " +"'employee.getHired()'"+ ", " + employee.getSalary()+ ", " +employee.getManagerId()+ ", " +employee.getDepartmentId() + ")";
        connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("select * from employee");

        ResultSet resultSet = ps2.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
            Employee emp = new Employee(... );

        return emp;
    }
```

Comment: It seems that your sql statement is not quoted in a way you would expect it to be. Fix that and report any exception/errors that you are getting back from the database, if any?

Comment: Ok, but steps which I didare correct for add to database this sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, better not use such approach:

```java
String sql = "insert into employee VALUES(" +employee.getId() + ", " + "'employee.getFullName().getFirstName()'" + ", " +"'employee.getFullName().getLastName()'"+ ", " +"'employee.getFullName().getMiddleName()'"+ ", " +  "'employee.getPosition()'" + ", " +"'employee.getHired()'"+ ", " + employee.getSalary()+ ", " +employee.getManagerId()+ ", " +employee.getDepartmentId() + ")";
```

you can have an [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in that case.

Instead use

```java
String sql = "insert into employee values (?, ?, ...)";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1, employee.getId());
statement.setString(2, employee.getFullName().getFirstName());
...
```

For your problem you can try something like this:

```java
public Employee save(Employee employee) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionSource.instance().createConnection();;
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);) {
        
        statement.setInt(1, employee.getId());
        statement.setString(2, employee.getFullName().getFirstName());
        // ...

        int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

        if (affectedRows == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Creating employee failed, no rows affected.");
        }

        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                employe.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
            }
            else {
                throw new SQLException("Creating employe failed, no ID obtained.");
            }
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```